# What should be used to diagram an application's internal architecture?

Tags: architecture, uml, diagrams

I have an application that has several dependencies, including a Matlab library and a Microsoft Windows Media Player ActiveX control. How would I graphically depict the internal architecture of this application for documentation purposes? Would a [UML structure diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Structure_diagrams) be appropriate? If so, would it be as simple as the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

All diagrams showing more structure than behaviour, are called together "structure diagrams". But it is merely a classification term. You can't create a structure diagram, that is not a `class diagram`, a `component diagram`, an `object diagram` etc... You MUST choose.

The word "structure" is also in the name of `Composite Structure Diagram`. It shows the coordination of inner parts of classes and objects. It is the lowest level diagram of the UML. Obviously it is not what you need.

You are thinking on the highest level. The most common structure diagrams are `Component diagram` and `Deployment diagram`. They are intended for modelling of the whole architecture of the product. The second one shows also the HW structure of the product.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be clear, are you saying that a Component or Deployment diagram is the way to go?

Comment: Yes, start from component diagram and maybe afterwards you will develop some part of it into a deployment diagram.